# Spring Boot JPA Specification for Exists query

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

my table data looks like below,

```
Employee Table
EMP_ID   EMP_VERSION  EMP_STATUS  EMP_NAME
  123          1          ACTIVE     Kathy
  123          2          DRAFT      Kathy
  245          1          DRAFT      Sally
  389          1          ACTIVE     Adam
```

There could be more than one version of a Employee record with same Id but different version. Primary key is EMP_ID and EMP_VERSION. At any case there will be only one version of Employee record that will be ACTIVE.

My requirement is to create a sql that returns either ACTIVE version of an Employee, in case if there is no ACTIVE version then highest version record should be returned for a EMP_ID.

Below is the query I have formed,

```
select * from myschema.employee t where t.EMP_ID='123'
and ((not exists (select * from myschema.employee t1 where t1.EMP_ID=t.EMP_ID and t1.EMP_STATUS= 'ACTIVE') and t.EMP_VERSION = (select max(EMP_VERSION) from myschema.employee t2 where t2.EMP_ID = t.EMP_ID)) or t.EMP_STATUS = 'ACTIVE')
```

Is the above SQL query looks good ? or any other efficient way of doing it ? I wanted to convert it to hibernate specification to retrieve using JPA.